# Python os.path.exists issue with variables

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to run a python module that searches a table, and extracts data from some of the celss in that table (using the variable "LayerExpression").  In some instances, that cell contain a path name to another python file (for example, the table cell may have the following path name in it: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Working\PyFiles\Example.py').  My python program assigns each cell value to the variable "CommentsExpression" and then checks the variable to see if in fact it does reference a path name to an exisiting file (using os.path.exists()).  If that is the case, then my program will import that other python file as a module, and extract specific variables from it--in this example the variable "expression".

My issue is that, when I pull the path name from the table, assign it to the variable "CommentsExpression" and run it through os.path.exists(), it keeps coming up as false--even if the file path does in fact exist.  I have tried using r'[path name]', but no luck as a variable.  An example of my code is below.

```
import arcpy, os, re, array, sys, glob
from arcpy import env

CommentsExpression = ''
LayerExpression = '"Database - Fish Species"'
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(r'C:\Users\me\Documents\Working\PyFiles\Master_Table.py')
for row in rows:
LayerField = row.getValue("Layer")
if LayerField == LayerExpression:
    CommentsExpression = CommentsExpression = row.getValue(str("Comments"))
    print os.path.exists(CommentsExpression)
    CommentsExpressionOutput = os.path.basename(CommentsExpression)
    CommentsExpressionOutput = CommentsExpressionOutput.split('.')
    CommentsExpressionOutput = str(CommentsExpressionOutput[0])
    if os.path.exists(CommentsExpression) == True:
        print 'True'
        pyFile = __import__(CommentsExpressionOutput)
        print pyFile.codeblock
    else:
        print 'False'
```

Comment: Are the paths that CommentsExpression takes absolute paths?

Comment: They are the full path names, yes.

Comment: So your comment got me thinking, and I changed the following line from 'if os.path.exists(CommentsExpression) == True:'
 to if 'os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(CommentsExpression)) == True' and so far it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to praveen for helping me with this.  If I changed the following line from

```
if os.path.exists(CommentsExpression) == True:'
```

to instead

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(CommentsExpression)) == True
```

it seems to work.

Comment: I hope you didn't mean to put the whole expression inside single quotes.